# CPU Governor for Android

Tags: android, linux, cpu-speed

I am interested in developing a CPU Governor for Android.

I am fairly familiar with Android app development but I have no idea on kernel development.

I found a couple of books on Linux kernel dev but none of them talk about governors.

Can anyone please guide me on how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the kernel documentation for [governors](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt). To develop a governor you might need to take a look at cpu frequency too, you'll find it under Documentation/cpu-freq/ directory. Above them all, the most important thing is to read the kernel code, you'll find them under drivers/cpufreq/ directory.

Hope this will help. Happy hacking!